# Fill in missing dates in dataframe using the mean

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have dates that I'm pulling into a dataframe at regular intervals.
The data is generally well-formed, but sometimes there are bad data in an otherwise date column.

I would always expect to have a date in the parsed 9 digit form:

```
(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=335, tm_isdst=-1)
(2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0)
```

How should I check and fix this?

What I would like to do is replace whatever is not a date, with a date based on a variable that represents the last_update + 1/2 the update interval, so the items are not filtered out by later functions.

Data as shown is published_parsed from feedparser.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# date with ugly data
df_date_ugly = pd.DataFrame({'date': [
                             (2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0), 
                             (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0),
                            'None', '',
                             (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0)
                            ]})

# date is fine
df_date =  pd.DataFrame({'date': [
                             (2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0), 
                             (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0),
                             (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0)
                            ]})

Pseudocode
  if the original_date is valid
     return original_date
  else
     return substitute_date
```

Comment: Could you edit your question, to show how the date is supposed to be? Specifically, in (2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0) why are you reading in (0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0)

Comment: Data as shown is the published_parsed entry attribute from feedparser, it comes as 9 integers.

Comment: What does 1, 363, 0 represent? The more you explain the easier it will be for everyone to help you, even those who may not be familiar with feedparser but are familiar with pandas. Also, please include your desired output for the last_update + 1/2 values.

Comment: Sure -- (tm_year=2000, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=335, tm_isdst=-1)

Comment: I'd expect a date like (2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0)  --but, replacing with just the trimmed date, but the long form is also ok.

Comment: You have 2 missing values, do you want to fill both of them in? Since, the values above and below the missing value are identical, you just want the same value for that? Have you considered using this [format](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)? I've tried answering to the best of my understanding but feel free to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I'm going to store in the pandas format. This is for processing on the way into pandas.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. If not please let us know, how to further help resolve your question.

Comment: I realized the 'None' was actually a None object, which just let me do a bit of alteration to your suggestion (if x != None), then the other replace solution. Thank you again for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When working with dates and times in pandas, convert them to a [pandas timestamp](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) using [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). To use this function, we will convert the list into a string with just the date and time elements. For your case, values that are not lists of length 9 will be considered *bad* and are replaced with a empty string `''`.

   ```
   #convert list into string with date & time
   #only elements with lists of length 9 will be parsed
   dates_df = df_date_ugly.applymap(lambda x: "{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}:{5}".format(x[0],x[1],x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]) if len(x)==9 else '')

   #convert to a pandas timestamp
   dates_df = pd.to_datetime(dates_df['date'], errors = 'coerce'))

       date
   0   2015-12-29 00:30:50
   1   2015-12-28 23:59:12
   2   NaT
   3   NaT
   4   2015-12-28 23:59:12
   ```
2. Find the indices where the dates are missing use [`pd.isnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

   ```
   >>>missing = pd.isnull(dates_df['date']).index
   >>>missing
   Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')
   ```
3. To set the missing date as the midpoint between 2 dates:

   ```
   start_date = dates_df.iloc[0,:]
   end_date = dates_df.iloc[4,:]
   missing_date = start_date + (end_date - start_date)/2
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
import calendar
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def tuple_to_timestamp(x):
    try:
        return calendar.timegm(x)               # 1
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'orig': [
    (2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0), 
    (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0),
    'None', '',
    (2015, 12, 30, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0)]})

ts = df['orig'].apply(tuple_to_timestamp)       # 2
# 0    1451349050
# 1    1451347152
# 2           NaN
# 3           NaN
# 4    1451519952
# Name: orig, dtype: float64

ts = ts.interpolate()                           # 3
# 0    1451349050
# 1    1451347152
# 2    1451404752
# 3    1451462352
# 4    1451519952
# Name: orig, dtype: float64

df['fixed'] = pd.to_datetime(ts, unit='s')      # 4

print(df)
```

yields

```
                                    orig               fixed
0   (2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0) 2015-12-29 00:30:50
1  (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0) 2015-12-28 23:59:12
2                                   None 2015-12-29 15:59:12
3                                        2015-12-30 07:59:12
4  (2015, 12, 30, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0) 2015-12-30 23:59:12
```

---

**Explanation**:

1. `calendar.timegm` converts each time-tuple to a timestamp. Unlike
   `time.mktime`, it interprets the time-tuple as being in UTC, not local time.
2. `apply` calls `tuple_to_timestamp` for each row of `df['orig']`.
3. The nice thing about timestamps is that they are numeric, so you can then use
   numerical methods such as `Series.interpolate` to fill in NaNs with interpolated
   values. Note that the two NaNs do *not* get filled with same interpolated value; their values are linearly interpolated based on their position as given by `ts.index`.
4. `pd.to_datetime` converts to timestamps to dates.